# Make select tag required if quantity is selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

What I wan't to achieve is when you have selected how many windows you have, but not have chosen what option you wan't, it should either give a error message or just set `Option 1` as the default when you submit the form.

I didn't post all of the code, because there is 31 windows that you can choose from, so it would be a very long question, so I just posted code for one window.

What I have tried so far:

- I have given the `Option 1` the `selected` attribute, but then it's applied all the time, when you submit the form and that's not how it supposed to be.
- I have tried to give the `<input type="number" name="quantity1" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK.">` the same php code as the `Option 1` so it would be like this:

  `<input type="number" name="quantity1" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK." value="60|Vindue 1" <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'quantity1']) && $_POST[ 'window1']=='60' ){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>` but then again it will always display the value of `Option 1` even if you didn't chose it

HTML and PHP for where you choose option, quantity and submit the form:

```
    <form action="" method="post">

    <div class="dropdown-option">
        <select id="select" name="window1" value="window1">
            <option>Choose Option</option>
            <option value="60|Window 1" <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'window1']) && $_POST[ 'window1']=='60' ){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>Option 1</option>
            <option value="40|Window 1" <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'window1']) && $_POST[ 'window1']=='40' ){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>Option 2</option>
            <option value="40|Window 1" <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'window1']) && $_POST[ 'window1']=='40' ){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>Option 3</option>
            <option value="85|Window 1" <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'window1']) && $_POST[ 'window1']=='85' ){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>Option 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-field">
        <input type="number" name="quantity1" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK.">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase;padding-bottom:70px;">Indtast dine oplysninger og modtag dit uforpligtende tilbud!</h3>

        <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
            <label for="first_name">Fornavn *</label>
            <input class="" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
            <label for="last_name">Efternavn *</label>
            <input class="" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-5 columns">
            <label for="address_street">Adresse *</label>
            <input class="" name="address_street" id="address_street" type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label for="zip_code">Postnummer *</label>
            <input class="" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" type="number" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-5 columns">
            <label for="city">By *</label>
            <input class="" name="city" id="city" type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
            <label for="email_address">Email *</label>
            <input class="" name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
            <label for="mobile_no">Telefon *</label>
            <input class="" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" type="tel" maxlength="8" required />
        </div>

        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="textarea">Besked</label>
            <textarea name="textarea" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="font-family: 'Dosis' !important;" value="Recieve and offer" class="submit-pris">
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Is PHP the right way or can this be done with jQuery?

I hope that someone can help me with this issue, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need a `onChange()` method, just add the required attribute to the select tag.

Comment: Like this: <select id="select" name="window1" value="window1" onChange()> ?

Comment: Nope..., Okey let me make an answer for you.

Comment: Use both jquery and php. jquery to reduce load on server and server checks to prevent hacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a jquery event for the control of your required attribute. Use the onchange event for this.

HTML:

```
<select id="select" name="window1" value="window1" >
  <option>Choose Option</option>
  <option value="60|Window 1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="40|Window 1" >Option 2</option>
  <option value="40|Window 1" >Option 3</option>
  <option value="85|Window 1" >Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="quantity1" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK." class="quantity">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".quantity").on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val!="")
        $("#select").attr("required", "required");
    else
        $("#select").removeAttr("required");
  })
})
```

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjou7xsz/)

If you need any further help then knock me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry but it's not working for me, I can submit the form even if no option is selected

Comment: Just inspect the select tag and see the required is add not not??, __You need to add the CDN of jQuery__.

Comment: You have put the jquery script after the CDN and i add one class into the quantity inputbox, ` class="quantity"`.

Comment: I am using the exact code that you have posted, but the select tag are not getting required

Comment: debug the jsfiddle i add in my answer.